# Improve read performance on ext4 on Centos with software raid1?

Tags: linux, performance, raid, software-raid, mongodb

I'm running a number of MongoDB nodes on dedicated servers running Centos6. Each machine has two SSDs which I have in Raid1 with two logical partitions:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        424G  233G  170G  58% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md1        496M  116M  355M  25% /boot

# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      451545792 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      16777088 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
```

It is recommended for MongoDB to reduce the read ahead from 256 to ~32 since that give about 16kb which is bigger than the average document.

```
# sudo blockdev --report
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0    480103981056   /dev/sdb
rw   256   512   512       2048     17179869696   /dev/sdb1
rw   256   512   512   33558528       536871424   /dev/sdb2
rw   256   512   512   34609152    462383047168   /dev/sdb3
rw   256   512  4096          0    480103981056   /dev/sda
rw   256   512   512       2048     17179869696   /dev/sda1
rw   256   512   512   33558528       536871424   /dev/sda2
rw   256   512   512   34609152    462383047168   /dev/sda3
rw   256   512  4096          0     17179738112   /dev/md0
rw   256   512  4096          0    462382891008   /dev/md2
rw   256   512  1024          0       536805376   /dev/md1
```

Since I have this structure, do I need to just run `sudo blockdev --setra 32 /dev/md2` ? Since the underlying drives still load 256 will this have any impact, or do I need to manually set the 32 block readahead for all /dev/sdaX and /dev/sdbX also?

Also, is an OS restart required to see the impact of the change in readahead?

Update: I think this is slightly different to the previous questioner, since here the RA for the mdX is much smaller than the underlying block device. I'm thinking that even if `/dev/md2` loads only 16kb, the underlying block device will still load 128kb each time.